# Highcharts chart width issue on lazy loading of stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in an Angular 5 web application with https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts library. I am implementing themes in the app and for this purpose I am loading the stylesheet dynamically.

The issue is, when a chart is created it takes up the full width of the container which is fine. But the problem is that the stylesheet gets loaded into the memory late due to network delay. This causes the chart to overflow the container.

This is reproducible as here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-theme-switch-highchart-problem-1

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load css you can add onload event handler. So only then show the chart:

```
  this.linkRef.onload = () => this.showChart();
```

Here is your changed example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-theme-switch-highchart-problem-1-wzqfaz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Awesome answer. I was sure that I would have to hack my way out but this is just beautiful.